# If statements in functions not working

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, getelementbyid

For some unknown reason the if statements in the checkID function have stopped working and are only displaying 'OK' no matter what input is entered. I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong but can someone take a look at my code. At the moment the code only seems to be running the last if statement in the function and only the last message which is "Ok".

This is my HTML:

```js
function begin() {
  var Name = document.forms["Cars"]["Name"].value;
  var NameID = document.forms["Cars"]["NameID"].value;
  var IDName = "";
  var PersonID = "";

  var checklength = Name.length;
  CheckName();
  console.log(checklength, checklength < 100)
  var checkIDlength = NameID.length;
  checkID();
  console.log(checkIDlength, checkIDlength < 100)
  return false;


  function CheckName() {
    if (checklength > 0 && checklength < 21) {
      IDName = "Ok"
    } else {
      IDName = "Invalid Name Length";
    }

    document.getElementById('IDName').innerHTML = IDName;
    return false;
  }

  function checkID() {
    if (checkIDlength != 6) {
      PersonID = "Invalid ID Length"
    }
    document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID

    if (NameID.indexOf('BR') === 0) {} else {
      PersonID = "Invalid ID Type"
      document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID

    }
    if (isNaN(NameID.Length != 2)) {
      PersonID = "The Last 2 Digits must be numeric";
    } else {
      PersonID = "OK"
      document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form name="Cars">
    <h1>Car Sales</h1>
    <p>Enter Name</p>
    <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase" name="Name"><br>
    <p id="IDName"></p>
    <p>Enter ID</p>
    <input type="text" name="NameID"><br>
    <p id="PersonID"></p>
    <br>
    <button onclick="return begin()">Calculate</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: `isNaN(NameID.Length !=2)` ... you want `.length` ... but this is always FALSE anyway, because `isNaN(true)` and `isNaN(false)` are always false, because `true` and `false` are not `NaN`

Comment: Where you have `isNaN(NameID.Length != 2)` the return value of the test will be true or false, which is coerced to 1 or 0, so *isNaN* always returns false and *PersonID* is set to OK. @Jaromanda X—snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've got this working by adding some return false into your if statements for the IDCheck function I'm using "BR1231" as my test case, I'm not sure if that is 100% valid but here is my code:

```
    function begin() {
  var Name = document.forms["Cars"]["Name"].value;
  var NameID = document.forms["Cars"]["NameID"].value;
  var IDName = "";
  var PersonID = "";

var checklength = Name.length;
CheckName();
console.log(checklength, checklength < 100)
var checkIDlength = NameID.length;
checkID();
console.log(checkIDlength, checkIDlength < 100)
return false;


function CheckName(){
  if (checklength >0 && checklength <21)
  {
IDName = "Ok"
  }
  else{
    IDName = "Invalid Name Length";
  }

  document.getElementById('IDName').innerHTML = IDName;
  return false;
}


function checkID(){
  if (checkIDlength !=6)
  {
    PersonID = "Invalid ID Length"

 document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID
 return false;
}

  if (NameID.indexOf('BR') === 0) {
  }
  else {
    PersonID = "Invalid ID Type"
   document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID
     return false;

}
   if (isNaN(NameID.Length !=2))
  {
   PersonID = "The Last 2 Digits must be numeric";
     return false;

 }
 else{
    PersonID = "OK"
    document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID

 }

}
}
```

Comment: thanks this seems to have fixed it! Although it still seems to be displaying "Ok" when 6 characters have been entered rather than BR and 4 digits. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: So I just entered "123123" and it's returning "Invalid ID Type" for me. Do you have this hosted on something that you can link me to so that I can see it in your live environment? You can always drop it on Amazon s3 quickly if you have an account.

Comment: 123123 also returns "invalid id type" for me but something like BRhfhf returns "Ok" even though it should only display "ok" if the 4 digits have been entered.

Comment: Can you give me a few examples of what is valid and what is not? Like BR1234 =  valid
BRqweq = Not valid 

If you can get that back to me I will retool this for you a bit.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. So BR1234 = valid but BRfddf is also valid. For some reason the isNaN doesn't seem to be having any affect.

Comment: var lastTwo = NameID.slice(-2);
       if (isNaN(lastTwo)) {
       PersonID = "The Last 2 Digits must be numeric";
       document.getElementById('PersonID').innerHTML = PersonID
       return false;

     }